# Indexing c++ vector in python gdb script

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I would like to write a python script to analyze the debugger state of an algorithm, but I can't figure out how to get the basic example of indexing a vector to work.

for example, when debugging the following file (gdb_test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
    for (const auto& element : v)
    {
        std::cout << element << std::endl;
    }
}
```

With gdb and sourcing the following script (print_vector.py) which is intended to print out the first three elements of an input vector provided by name:

```
import gdb
class print_vector(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super(print_vector, self).__init__('print_vector',
                                           gdb.COMMAND_SUPPORT,
                                           gdb.COMPLETE_FILENAME)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        # Access the variable from gdb.
        frame = gdb.selected_frame()

        args = arg.split('; ')
        val = frame.read_var(args[0])

        for i in range(3):
            print(val[0])
print_vector()
```

With commands:

```
g++ gdb_test.cpp -std=c++11 -g
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) b gdb_test.cpp:10
(gdb) r
(gdb) source print_vector.py
(gdb) print_vector v
```

I get the error

```
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> Cannot subscript requested type.: 
Error occurred in Python command: Cannot subscript requested type.
```

Which is referring to the `print(val[0])`-line. The problem is that `gdb.Value` objects can't be indexed as lists. Is there some other way to access the elements?

I have also tried things like `val['at'][0]` and `val['at(0)']`, neither of which works. Loading the elements one-by-one with one call to `gdb.parse_and_eval` each works but is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following function in c++11:

```
def vector_to_list(std_vector):
    out_list = []
    value_reference = std_vector['_M_impl']['_M_start']
    while value_reference != std_vector['_M_impl']['_M_finish']:
        out_list.append(value_reference.dereference())
        value_reference += 1

    return out_list
```

If `std_vector` is a `gdb.Value`-object holding a `std::vector<T>` this function returns a python list of `gdb.Value`-objects of type `T`. Based on this blog-post: https://hgad.net/posts/object-inspection-in-gdb/

I found this to be significantly faster than calling  `gdb.parse_and_eval['v[i]']` for all the `i`'s

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the C++ objects exposed to Python are not "first class" Python objects - so, they don't feature a Python `__getitem__` method that maps to the corresponding mechanism to get an item in the "C++" class of the object.

On the other hand, the API does expose a `parse_and_eval` method that will handle a string as if it was typed in the C++ source - therefore allowing one to use `v[i]` from Python in an easy way -

For the example above, you can change your Python source to:

```py
import gdb
class print_vector(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super(print_vector, self).__init__('print_vector',
                                           gdb.COMMAND_SUPPORT,
                                           gdb.COMPLETE_FILENAME)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        # Access the variable from gdb.
        frame = gdb.selected_frame()

        args = arg.split('; ')
        valname = args[0]

        for i in range(3):
            content_value = gdb.parse_and_eval(f"{valname}[{i}]")
            print(int(content_value))
print_vector()
```

To see this working. For more complex code, it may be worth to create a wrapper class in Python for gdb.Value objects that will implement a `__getitem__` that does this automatically.

Comment: I did try this but it's very slow for large vectors of structs, presumably due to overhead in the `parse_and_eval` function. Ideally there would be a way to access the elements directly  from the full `Value`-object. It should technically be possible since adding  `print(val)` to the code above yields a string with all the elements, which means they are actually all loaded into python. Worst case I suppose I could parse that string...